# Clearing cookies used by before and after wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress website and I added a form to capture user email before they view a video using the before and after plugin.

The problem I have now is that a user filled in the form once, the cookies are not being cleared to enable the user to enter an email adress before viewing the video.

I changed the following code but am not sure it works.
I need cookies to be deleted after a set time e.g. 5 hours, how do I achieve this?

```
function clear_goal_cookies()
{

    // clear session
    foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value)
    {
        // test if $key starts with 'goal_'
        if (strpos($key, 'goal_') === 0) {
            // it does! so delete it
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
        }
    }

    // clear cookies
    foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value)
    {           
        // delete cookie if it starts with 'b_a_a_g_'
        if (strpos($key, 'b_a_a_g_') === 0) {
            unset($_COOKIE[$key]);
            // set a new cookie with its expiration in the past 
            // so it will be deleted on next page load
            //setcookie($key, '', time() - 3600, '/');  COMMENTED THIS OUT
            // let the cookie be deleted after 24 hours
            setcookie($key, '', time() + 86400, '/'); // 86400 = 1 day I ADDED THIS
        }
    }

    // delete all goal completion post meta values for the current user
    $browser_hash = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $meta_key = 'b_a_goal_complete_' . $browser_hash;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'b_a_goal',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'meta_key' => $meta_key
    );
    $goals_completed = get_posts($args);
    if ( !empty($goals_completed) && is_array($goals_completed) ) {
        foreach($goals_completed as $goal) {
            delete_post_meta($goal->ID, $meta_key);
        }           
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep the cookies but your 'clear cookies' `foreach` loop removes it with every page load.

See the comments:

```
// set a new cookie with its expiration in the past 
// so it will be deleted on next page load
```

The `unset($_COOKIE[$key]);` does the cookie removal. If you dont want this, comment it out.

You want the cookie 'lifetime' to be 5 hours. This is 18.000 seconds:

`setcookie($key, '', time() + 18000, '/');`

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the above hence my time set to 1 day but it doesn't work. The user is still able to view the video without entering their email on a fresh page or after a day. The cookie is not being cleared. Is there a way I can do this in my site javascript - clear the website cookies when the browser is closed or after some time?

Comment: You're only showing a small part of the code. It's very difficult to pin point what's going on.... Before and After plugin?? Isn't this an image comparison slider? Cookie creation/edit can be done with PHP and JS. I would go with JS + Ajax call that saves the e-mail to database. 1. Check if cookie is set. 2. No cookie then show e-mail input and block video play. 3. On e-mail submit, set cookie, do Ajax call & start video play.... If you do it wright you can automatically bind this script to every video on your site. This is not that difficult, can be considered as a beginner project.

Comment: Extra Note: If you only use JS to block video play, know that script kiddies can bypass this. If you want to be 100% sure an e-mail is entered, then you can send the stream or video file link with the returning ajax call and load it after e-mail submit. This would require some more PHP scripting to retrieve the correct video source.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Bjorn. I searched for a betternway to manage user data capture and found a simpler plugin.